# Flume classpath contains multiple SLF4J bindings, fetching twitter data

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng, flume-twitter

when fetching twitter data using command:

```
./bin/flume-ng agent -n TwitterAgent -c conf -f /usr/lib/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf/flume.conf
```

a warning popups in terminal saying:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/apache-flume-1.7.0-bin/lib/slf4j-logj12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticBinder
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

i am using quickstart cloudera 5.10 and flume 1.7.0.

Comment: It's only a warning. Is it causing data loss? Actual Errors? Ignore it

Comment: No there is no data loss. 
But I cannot fetch any data from Twitter.